# How can I force to load / create pdb files for a dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have downloaded the latest version of SFML (a library) which includes source files, dlls, headers, and .lib files.
I have no problem using the library and it's linked dynamically.
I'd like to be able to step through the library code in the debugger (I used to be able to which earlier version), but now I can only see the assembly.
What is the usual way to generate pdb files to so?
thanks

Comment: You're going to have to build SFML from source and generate PDBs during the build, if the website doesn't have downloads for the PDB files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally Visual Studio 2010 should automatically generate .pdb files for you (if you build in debug mode). Take a look in your Debug output folder. You can see where and what .pdb is being generated from your project settings;

[image: Generate PDB]

Sterren

Comment: The option is not limited to debug mode. You can have symbols generated for release mode as well. It is just a lot harder to follow the optimized code in the debugger.